# extjs datagrid selection failing ONLY sometimes

Tags: extjs, grid

I receive an error when I click on my ExtJS grid but only if I click different selections in a short amount of time.  So if I click on a row, my DOSTUFF method works, but if I keep clicking on different rows I eventually get an error.  Basically because when you click on a row, lots of different things are happening, and I think its just not letting all the recalculations get completed before moving on.

Here is a picture of the error
[image: error picture]

This is my first ExtJS project... how can I see where this is failing?  And if it is because I am not letting the previous calculations finish.. how can I prevent this?

Here is the method that is called when I click a row in datagrid.

```
    onManagerSelection: function (selectedAccountNumber) {

    //set variables
    var me = this;
    var calculatedPositionsDataGrid = Ext.getCmp('calculatedPositionsGridID2');
    var calculatedPositionsDataStore = calculatedPositionsDataGrid.store;

    var detailsDataGrid = Ext.getCmp('detailsGridID');
    var detailsDataStore = detailsDataGrid.store;

    var sectorSummaryDataGrid = Ext.getCmp('sectorGridID');
    var sectorSummaryDataStore = sectorSummaryDataGrid.store;

    var accountSummaryDataGrid = Ext.getCmp('summaryGridID');
    var accountSummaryDataStore = accountSummaryDataGrid.store;

    var selectedSector = '';

    //clear out datastores
    detailsDataGrid.getStore().removeAll();
    detailsDataGrid.view.refresh();

    sectorSummaryDataGrid.getStore().removeAll();
    sectorSummaryDataGrid.view.refresh();

    //clear out labels
    var textfieldSector = this.view.down('#textfieldSector');
    textfieldSector.setValue('');

    //populate grid: details
    var groupedStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myGroupStoreID');
    me.populateDetailsStore(calculatedPositionsDataStore, detailsDataStore, groupedStore, selectedAccountNumber, selectedSector);

    //populate grid: sector summary
    var groupedSectorStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myGroupSectorStoreID');
    me.populateSectorSummaryStore(calculatedPositionsDataStore, sectorSummaryDataStore, groupedSectorStore, selectedAccountNumber);

    //populate label Total Account Pnl
    me.populateLabelTotalAccount(accountSummaryDataStore, selectedAccountNumber);

},
```

Comment: Have a look at the buffer config when setting listeners. This might help with the race issue you're having.

Comment: thanks Jeff... what am I looking for in buffer config for listeners?

Comment: When you set up the listener for select with the callback function onManagerSelection, you should be able to set the configuration for "buffer" which would limit the time between activations.

Comment: so I added a buffer of 2000.  Which I believe is delaying request by 2 seconds.  Either way things seem to be working more smoothly so thanks.  Is that what buffer does? delay the request of selection?

Comment: My understanding of it is that if there are multiple requests in the 2 seconds buffer, it will take only the most recent one and ignore the rest.

Comment: perfect... thank you